# Xcode 6-beta, following Swift iBook, typing numbers.map crashes Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm going through the new Swift iBook on my new Mac and I'm in the intro/tutorial section of the book where it gives an overview of the language. At the end of the section on functions, it gives an example of a closure with one called "numbers.map". Every time I attempt to type in "numbers.map" into my source code, without fail, Xcode crashes. A gray box pops up that says: SourceKitService Terminated   Editor Functionality temporarily limited. It then gives me a crash report and asks me to reopen Xcode. This message appears to tell me the crash happens on thread 21: Crashed Thread:  21  IDEPlaygroundExecutionSessionThread(pid=406. This seems to be the same thread that crashes every time. And here is the report for the thread:

```
Thread 21 Crashed:: IDEPlaygroundExecutionSessionThread(pid=406)
0   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010e53fd21 swift::IterableDeclContext::loadAllMembers() const + 17
1   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010e537dac swift::NominalTypeDecl::getMembers(bool) const + 28
2   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010e794582 (anonymous namespace)::LowerType::visitAnyStructType(swift::CanType, swift::StructDecl*) + 194
3   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010e792040 swift::Lowering::TypeLowering const* swift::CanTypeVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::LowerType, swift::Lowering::TypeLowering const*>::visit<>(swift::CanType) + 128
4   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010e791e46 swift::Lowering::TypeConverter::getTypeLoweringForUncachedLoweredType(swift::Lowering::TypeConverter::TypeKey) + 118
5   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010e7918b6 swift::Lowering::TypeConverter::getTypeLowering(swift::Lowering::AbstractionPattern, swift::Type, unsigned int) + 2198
6   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010e7b2337 swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitInitializationForVarDecl(swift::VarDecl*, bool, swift::Type) + 295
7   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010e7b2bef swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::InitializationForPattern, void, void, void, std::__1::unique_ptr<swift::Lowering::Initialization, std::__1::default_delete<swift::Lowering::Initialization> >, void, void>::visit(swift::Pattern*) + 415
8   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010e7b2963 swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::visitPatternBindingDecl(swift::PatternBindingDecl*) + 51
9   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010e7ebbdc swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::visitBraceStmt(swift::BraceStmt*) + 332
10  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010e7a361b swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::emitSourceFile(swift::SourceFile*, unsigned int) + 395
11  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010e7a38cb swift::SILModule::constructSIL(swift::Module*, swift::SourceFile*, unsigned int) + 331
12  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010e7a39b0 swift::performSILGeneration(swift::SourceFile&, unsigned int) + 32
13  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010eb24925 lldb_private::SwiftExpressionParser::Parse(lldb_private::Stream&, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) + 9433
14  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010e912fe8 lldb_private::ClangUserExpression::Parse(lldb_private::Stream&, lldb_private::ExecutionContext&, lldb_private::ExecutionPolicy, bool, bool, unsigned int) + 1022
15  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010e914738 lldb_private::ClangUserExpression::Evaluate(lldb_private::ExecutionContext&, lldb_private::EvaluateExpressionOptions const&, char const*, char const*, lldb_private::SharingPtr<lldb_private::ValueObject>&, lldb_private::Error&, unsigned int) + 496
16  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010ea60d65 lldb_private::Target::EvaluateExpression(char const*, lldb_private::StackFrame*, lldb_private::SharingPtr<lldb_private::ValueObject>&, lldb_private::EvaluateExpressionOptions const&) + 367
17  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010d23babc lldb::SBFrame::EvaluateExpression(char const*, lldb::SBExpressionOptions const&) + 598
18  com.apple.dt.IDELanguageSupportUI   0x0000000114cea802 -[IDEPlaygroundExecutionSession _executePlaygroundSource] + 603
19  com.apple.dt.IDELanguageSupportUI   0x0000000114ce9631 -[IDEPlaygroundExecutionSession handleInternalSessionEvent:] + 482
20  com.apple.dt.IDELanguageSupportUI   0x0000000114ce8837 -[IDEPlaygroundExecutionSession listenForEvents] + 535
21  com.apple.dt.IDELanguageSupportUI   0x0000000114ce8479 IDEPlaygroundExecutionSessionThread(void*) + 132
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a342899 _pthread_body + 138
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a34272a _pthread_start + 137
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a346fc9 thread_start + 13
```

...And there is a summary at the bottom too that looks like this:

```
Thread 21 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00007fb939a83dd8  rbx: 0x0000f00000000079  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000f00000000009
  rdi: 0x0000f00000000079  rsi: 0x0000000000000001  rbp: 0x000000012648ab10  rsp: 0x000000012648aae0
   r8: 0x00007fb9341658c8   r9: 0x00007fb939cd4880  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000001
  r12: 0x000000012648ad58  r13: 0x00007fb9341658c8  r14: 0x0000f00000000079  r15: 0x0000000000000001
  rip: 0x000000010e53fd21  rfl: 0x0000000000010297  cr2: 0x00007fb939ce8000


Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     13
```

Is this a problem that can be fixed or likely just an issue Apple will have to patch with an update? Thanks.

Comment: If Xcode is crashing, it's a bug. You should file a [bug report](http://radar.apple.com/) with Apple.

Comment: Xcode also crashes for me when I try to `print(arr, n)` where `arr` is an array and `n` is an `Int`. shan't be happening, yet it does. It is a bug. But since Xcode 6 is beta software, you should expect bugs.

Comment: I've got the same problem, funny thing is if you copy the whole code into playground instead of type only `numbers.map`, it won't crash and works fine.

Comment: This question concerns a problem with an IDE that is still in beta.

Comment: I can't answer this, maybe because it's on-hold?... a small workaround to this is to edit the **.swift** file and remove the last 1 or 2 lines, then open the **.playground** file again with xCode. That **.swift** file is inside the **.playground** bundle. To open it up, right-click on it and select **Show Package Contents**, then open the **.swift** file using your favorite text editor.